# KeyError(f"{labels[mask].tolist()} not found in axis")

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, uncatVulns with 982 rows and vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable with 183 entries.  The data comes from a monthly CSV report with the same columns, etc.  I'm trying to drop any rows from uncatVulns that are also in vulnsWithNewSeverithyOrFixable.  df.info() on both confirms this and that the columns are the same.  I have tried both:

uncatVulns.drop(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.index, inplace=True)

and

uncatVulns = uncatVulns.drop(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.index).

In both cases I am getting:

```
2023-10-05 09:51:15,849:INFO: *** uncatVulns.info:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 982 entries, 0 to 1589
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------             --------------  ----- 
 0   Cluster            982 non-null    object
 1   Namespace          982 non-null    object
 2   Deployment         982 non-null    object
 3   Image              982 non-null    object
 4   Component          982 non-null    object
 5   CVE                982 non-null    object
 6   Fixable            982 non-null    bool  
 7   Component Upgrade  368 non-null    object
 8   Severity           982 non-null    object
 9   Discovered At      982 non-null    object
 10  Reference          982 non-null    object
 11  Month              982 non-null    object
dtypes: bool(1), object(11)
memory usage: 93.0+ KB
2023-10-05 09:51:15,851:INFO: None
2023-10-05 09:51:15,851:INFO: 
2023-10-05 09:51:15,851:INFO: 
2023-10-05 09:51:15,851:INFO: *** vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.info():
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 183 entries, 908 to 1589
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------             --------------  ----- 
 0   Cluster            183 non-null    object
 1   Namespace          183 non-null    object
 2   Deployment         183 non-null    object
 3   Image              183 non-null    object
 4   Component          183 non-null    object
 5   CVE                183 non-null    object
 6   Fixable            183 non-null    bool  
 7   Component Upgrade  77 non-null     object
 8   Severity           183 non-null    object
 9   Discovered At      183 non-null    object
 10  Reference          183 non-null    object
 11  Month              183 non-null    object
dtypes: bool(1), object(11)
memory usage: 17.3+ KB
2023-10-05 09:51:15,852:INFO: None
2023-10-05 09:51:15,852:INFO: 
2023-10-05 09:51:15,852:INFO: 
2023-10-05 09:51:15,852:ERROR:   *** len(uncatVulns) : 982
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robertharris/Security/POAnM/monthlyvulndelta/./POAM_Mixologist.py", line 466, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/robertharris/Security/POAnM/monthlyvulndelta/./POAM_Mixologist.py", line 320, in main
    uncatVulns = uncatVulns.drop(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.index)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5347, in drop
    return super().drop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4711, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4753, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 6992, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask].tolist()} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[1045, 1054, 1056, 1060, 1069, 1071, 1075, 1084, 1086, 1090, 1099, 1101, 1105, 1114, 1116, 1120, 1129, 1131, 1135, 1139] not found in axis'
```

Thought or help please?  I've been googling and searching for about 3 days on this one error.

Comment: Does this help ?  `result = uncatVulns.merge(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)`

Comment: It passes, but I'll have to put it in a few places to see if it clears up more errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message you received indicates that some of the indices in `vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable` are not present in `uncatVulns`. When you try to drop rows based on indices that do not exist in the dataframe, pandas raises a `KeyError`.

Instead of dropping by index, you could drop rows based on the actual values, that is, rows that match across columns, using the `merge` method.

```
# Merge both dataframes and keep only rows that are unique to 'uncatVulns'
result = uncatVulns.merge(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

Here, we are using an outer merge with the `indicator=True` flag. This adds a special column _merge which tells us if the row is from the left DataFrame only, right only, or both. We then filter for rows where `_merge` is `left_only`, which means those rows that are only in `uncatVulns` and not in `vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable`. Thn, we drop the _merge column.

Hopefully, this should result in a dataframe that contains only the rows from `uncatVulns` that aren't present in `vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable` based on the actual row values, not the indices.

---

Edit: To address the comment to my answer:

> What if i need to ignore a column? For example column 12 is "Month' which will be different between the 2 dataframes. Everything else though should be compared.

```
# Merge both dataframes on all columns except the last one
# Keep only rows that are unique to 'uncatVulns'
result = uncatVulns.merge(vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.iloc[:, :-1], 
                          left_on=uncatVulns.columns[:-1].tolist(), 
                          right_on=vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable.columns[:-1].tolist(),
                          indicator=True, how='outer'
                         ).query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

Here, we have used the `.iloc` method to select all columns of the `vulnsWithNewSeverityOrFixable` dataframe except the last one (column 12).  We are instructing the merge to consider all columns of both dataframes, again excluding the last column (column 12). The `.columns[:-1]` returns the labels of all columns except the last one, and `.tolist()` converts these labels into a list. By specifying the `left_on` and `right_on` arguments this way, we are effectively telling the merge method to use these columns (all except the last one) as keys for the merge operation.

In summary the merge operation will match rows based on the values in the first 11 columns of both dataframes, completely ignoring the 12th column.

Comment: Makes sense and resolves the issue, now to figure out some other math oddities.

Comment: What if i need to ignore a column?  For example column 12 is "Month' which will be different between the 2 dataframes.  Everything else though should be compared.

Comment: Just delete that column first ? Or am I missing your point ? Anyway, can take a look at that in the morning, just about to sleep now  :)

Comment: I mean just ignore column 12, "Month" when doing the comparision since it's guaranteed to be different, but shouldn't be accounted for.

Comment: OK that should be possible. I have just edited the answer. Hopefully that does the trick ?